# Make an object rotate to angle of tilt with accelerometer in CoronaSDK?

Tags: lua, rotation, coronasdk, accelerometer, angle

with my first game I have a doodle I control with the accelerometer. In many games I've seen that when the device is titled the object (in my case a doodle fish) rotate towards the tilt so it gives an illusion the "fish" swim down and if the device is tilted up and down the "fish" swims up and down.

How do I write that in lua when working with Corona SDK?

Here is my code for moving the doodle so far;

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
system.setAccelerometerInterval( 50 )

_W = display.contentWidth
_H = display.contentHeight

local bg = display.newImageRect("images/bg.png", 480, 320)
      bg:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint)
      bg.x = _W/2
      bg.y = _H/2

local player = display.newImageRect("images/doodle.png", 128, 64)
     player:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint)
     player.x = _W/2
     player.y = _H/2

-- Set up the Accelerometer values in Landscape

local motionX = 0
local motionY = 0                

local function onAccelerate( event )
     motionX = 10 * event.yGravity;
     motionY = 10 * event.xGravity;
end

Runtime:addEventListener ("accelerometer", onAccelerate);

-- Make the player move on tilt.

local function movePlayer (event)
    player.x = player.x + motionX;
    player.y = player.y + motionY;
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", movePlayer)

    local function screenBoundaries (event)

        -- Left side boundaries
    if player.x < 0 + player.width/2 then 
       player.x = 0 + player.width/2
    end

        -- Right side boundaries
    if player.x > display.contentWidth - player.width/2 then
       player.x = display.contentWidth - player.width/2
    end

        -- Upper boundaries
    if player.y < 0 + player.height/2 then 
       player.y = 0 + player.height/2
    end

        -- Lower boundaries
    if player.y > display.contentHeight - player.height/2 then 
       player.y = display.contentHeight - player.height/2
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", screenBoundaries)
```

---

EDIT;

I've tried to make the player rotate to tilt but it's not working, it doesn't return any errors when I run it in the simulator, what am I doing wrong?

Basically what I want to do is when the accelerometer y value increase/decrease the player(fish) swim up and down but I only want it to tilt moderately (0 to +/- 45 degrees) or what ever seems realistic. Perhaps 25 -35 degrees is optimal?

My math is not up to date so I apologize for that, can someone please help me with this?

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar)
system.setAccelerometerInterval( 50 )

_W = display.contentWidth
_H = display.contentHeight

local ceil = math.ceil
local pi = math.pi
local atan2 = math.atan2
local playerRotation


 -- Put the doodle fish in the center if the screen.
    local player = display.newImageRect("images/doodle.png", 128, 64)
    player:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint)
    player.x = _W/2
    player.y = _H/2

 -- My rotation function, not sure how to do it right.

    local function getPlayerRotationAngle(xGravity, yGravity)
    angle = math.atan2(xGravity, yGravity)

    angle = angle*(180/pi)

    playerRotate = ceil(360 - angle(xGravity, yGravity))

    return playerRotate
     end

 -- Set up the Accelerometer values in Landscape

    local motionX = 0
    local motionY = 0 

    local function onAccelerate( event )
          motionX = 5 * event.yGravity;
          motionY = 5 * event.xGravity;

          -- Should I put the rotation here or down in the movePlayer function?

          player.rotation = playerRotate(event.yGravity, event.xGravity);
    end

    Runtime:addEventListener ("accelerometer", onAccelerate);

 -- Make the player move on tilt.

    function movePlayer (event)

         player.x = player.x + motionX
         player.y = player.y + motionY


    end

    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", movePlayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your overall code looks good.
Several games I did use something similar.

What jumps out is you mentioning

> I've tried to make the player rotate to tilt but it's not working, it doesn't return any errors when I run it in the simulator, what am I doing wrong?

Are you actually running the code on a device?
The Corona SDK simulator does not support simulation for the accelerometer so the event will never fire.

If you are running on the device, include the [Crawl Space Library](http://developer.anscamobile.com/code/crawl-space-library).
This will allow you to print() any form of data including tables.
Then add

```
print(event)
```

to your onAccelerate() function, hook your device up to your development machine and watch the console for the data you actually receive. (Assuming you're developing for iOS using a Mac, use **iPhone Configuration Utility** to get the data). Then debug from there.

Include

```
io.output():setvbuf("no")
```

at the beginning of your main.lua to disable console output caching on the device first. Otherwise the console output of your device will be buffered and hard to debug.

Comment: I use the cmote app to test accelerometer on the simulator, it works really good. The accelerometer works fine and the fish follows the tilt of the device. What I want help with is to make the fish rotate a little so it looks like it's swimming up/down when the Y value changes. I use the print() function but just not in this post.

Comment: I actually think it would be better if the fish rotated up/down when the X value changes? So if I could get some help with the getPlayerRotationAngle function as it does not rotate the player as it is now and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: In that case, what jumps out immediately is that your function is called "getPlayerRotationAngle" yet, you call "playerRotate" (the name of your local return value) in "player.rotation = playerRotate(event.yGravity, event.xGravity);" and never call the actual function.

Comment: How do you suggest I do this, I can't make the "fish" rotate to the angle I tilt.